# PostgreSQL: Error :too many parameter specified for raise

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run my stored procedure scripts . There are 21 scripts amongst them 18 successfully executed but 3 of them are not executing. One of the script which is failing is given below   (I am using PostgreSQL 9.5)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_temp_eid_table (tempPatientMappingTableName IN text ,errorMsg OUT text) 
RETURNS text AS $body$
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE 'create table ' ||  tempPatientMappingTableName || ' (
        ENCOUNTER_MAP_ID        varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        ENCOUNTER_MAP_ID_SOURCE     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        PROJECT_ID              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PATIENT_MAP_ID          varchar(200), 
        PATIENT_MAP_ID_SOURCE   varchar(50), 
        ENCOUNTER_ID            varchar(200) NOT NULL,
        ENCOUNTER_ID_SOURCE     varchar(50) ,
        ENCOUNTER_NUM           numeric, 
        ENCOUNTER_MAP_ID_STATUS    varchar(50),
        PROCESS_STATUS_FLAG     char(1),
        UPDATE_DATE timestamp, 
        DOWNLOAD_DATE timestamp, 
        IMPORT_DATE timestamp, 
        SOURCESYSTEM_CD varchar(50)
    ) WITH OIDS';
    EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX idx_' || tempPatientMappingTableName || '_eid_id ON ' || tempPatientMappingTableName || '  (ENCOUNTER_ID, ENCOUNTER_ID_SOURCE, ENCOUNTER_MAP_ID, ENCOUNTER_MAP_ID_SOURCE, ENCOUNTER_NUM)';
EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX idx_' || tempPatientMappingTableName || '_stateid_eid_id ON ' || tempPatientMappingTableName || '  (PROCESS_STATUS_FLAG)';  
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE NOTICE '%%%', SQLSTATE,  ' - ' , SQLERRM;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

i am getting error stating that

```
" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: too many parameters specified for RAISE 
Where: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "create_temp_eid_table" near line 23". 
Please check the image for clear error message.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Raise Notice` takes only two parameters

What you want probably is:

```
RAISE NOTICE '%%%', SQLSTATE || ' - ' || SQLERRM;
```

[Errors and Messages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html)

Answer (score 2):

Problem here is that two consecutive % are considered as one %. According to doc:

> Write %% to emit a literal %.

This means that %%% is generally % plus one argument and that is why this error occurred. You can separate %%% with space, or pass one argument and make concatenation of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved by erasing one %

"Problem here is that two consecutive % are considered as one %"

have a nice day!

Hiram